# strange issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very strange issue with jQuery.

The problem:

```
$("#button-prev").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

This doesn't work. If I check with Firebug I see disabled="" as element attribute

But for example this

```
$("#button-prev").attr("disablea", "disabled");
```

works as you should expect. Anyone an idea what it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disabled` is a **boolean** property. Therefore it's just enough if a `truthy` value is set.

```
<button disabled>foo</button>
```

would work aswell in most browsers. You need to either completely remove the property by using

```
$('#button-prev').removeAttr('disabled');
```

or set it explicitly to `false / 0`

```
$('#button-prev').attr('disabled', false);
```

It's a common mistake and pretty confusing, consider, a call like

```
$(element).attr('disabled', 'false');
```

would also **disable** the element. Since you passed in a `string value` which is a `truthy` value.

Further info: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Comment: I want to disable the button. If I do $('#button-prev').attr('disabled', false); the complete property is removed. If I do $('#button-prev').attr('disabled', true); or with other true values I see this in Firebug disabled=""

Comment: @Derk: Yes this is a correct behavior. As I described, the property is totally satisfied if it's just "there", the value is not important.

Comment: Whatever value I try, the element is not disabled

Comment: You are right. The problem was that I checked in my CSS for [disabled="disabled"]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, if the button *is* disabled? I just tried it with the "Post Your Answer" button on this page, and although Firebug doesn't show anything in the HTML tab, the DOM tab reveals, that the disabled attribute is set (and behold, I can't click).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the attr for that is "true" or "false"...
Try:  $("#button-prev").attr("disabled", true);
Make sure "button-prev" is the ID for the button.

Answer (score 0):

In plain ol' JavaScript, it's a simple as

```
document.getElementById('button-prev').disabled = true;
```

This is one of the few occassions where I think it would be easier not to use jQuery

Comment: This also doesn't work for me, probably this is also what jQuery does internally